# Can I make a WebRequest without setting ContentLength

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

This is a goofy question but I'm testing a tool and need to create an unusual situation. I want to make a POST request that sends several megabytes of data to a web server but I don't want the Content-Length set. (It would be OK if it was set to 0 or -1.)

HttpWebRequest automatically sets request.ContentLength to the length of the RequestStream buffer. Is there a way to prevent or circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a POST request without setting the Content-Length header by using chunked encoding. With chunked encoding, you send the data in segments (or "chunks") instead of in a single piece. This is useful when you need to send data to a server but you don't know the size.

Chunked encoding is part of HTTP 1.1 as defined by [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-25)

.NET provides the [SendChunked feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.sendchunked.aspx) to support this scenario